# Using Powershell invoke-expression to uninstall Java on all domain computers

Tags: java, powershell, invoke-command

I can ps-session to a remote machine, run the following, and successfully uninstall Java:
`invoke-expression "msiexec /q /x '{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0}' "`

I am trying to create a script that will uninstall from all domain computers:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
function uninstallJava {
$badcomp = @()
$CompList = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'name -like "*"' | select -ExpandProperty Name
foreach ($c in $CompList) {

Try {
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $computer 
Invoke-expression "msiexec.exe /q /x '{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0}' "
}

Catch {
$badcomp += $c
}

}

}
uninstallJava
"the following servers could not be reached:"
$badcomp
```

I don't receive any errors, but it doesn't uninstall Java from the remote machines.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: The call to your function is inside the scriptblock of your function. So not only does it not start, but if it did you would have an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks Frode, my mistake. I fixed that and it calls the function, but does not work.

Comment: Have you considered using WMI/CIM calls to uninstall the program? if it's MSIExec friendly you should be able to do that. [See here for details](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/12/14/use-powershell-to-find-and-uninstall-software.aspx)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$badcomp = @()

Function uninstallJava {
    $CompList = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'name -like "*"' | Select -ExpandProperty Name
    ForEach ($c In $CompList) {
        Try {
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $c {
                C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C msiexec.exe /q /x '{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0}'
            }
        } Catch {
            $badcomp += $c
        }
    }
}
uninstallJava

Write-Host "the following servers could not be reached:"
$badcomp
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I tried your solution as-is and it did not work. If I just Enter-PSSession to a machine and run `msiexec.exe /q /x '{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0}'` that works. If I run the whole function and just test to a single machine by replacing * with a "testcomp" that doesn't work either.

Comment: I actually didn't test the remote execute, I assumed you had tested and just needed syntax help with your script. I updated the code to call Invoke-Command. Give it a try now.

Comment: I just tested and that worked! This was similar to other solutions I tried.  I guess taking out the scriptblock parameter and specifying the path with the /C option instead did the trick. Thanks for the help Nathan. I would upvote, but I don't have the required reputation yet.

Comment: Good to hear. You can accept the answer if you'd like though. :)

Answer (score -1):

You should be using `Invoke-Command`, not `Enter-PSSession`. The latter is for interactively working in another machine. The former is for running a command in the other machine and getting back results (if any).

Basically, your try block should look like this:

```powershell
Try {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $c -ScriptBlock { msiexec.exe /q /x '{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0}' }
}
```

If you want more detailed control and error information, consider [using WMI to uninstall the product](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/12/14/use-powershell-to-find-and-uninstall-software.aspx) instead of shelling out to `msiexec`.

Comment: Thanks briantist. I tried replacing the Try block with what you suggested and it did not work. I also tried just running the Invoke-command `Invoke-Command -ComputerName testcomp -ScriptBlock { msiexec.exe /q /x '{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0}' }` and it did not work either. As stated, invoke-expression works...seems like invoke-command should too...

Comment: I can't say for sure why the `msiexec` call is not working. You could check for return codes or some kind of status, and then return that to the calling code. You would do those checks *inside* the scriptblock.

Comment: hmm, that's little above my head, but I'll see what I can figure out.

Comment: I missed the link to the WMI uninstall earlier. Thanks for that. BTW, it worked with Nathan's suggestion which was very similar to yours. thanks again.